# Why is sphinx autodoc failing to generate links to some function parameter types?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I've got sphinx autodoc working with [sphinx-autodoc-typehints](https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints) and [intersphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) such that `:class:` references render links when used in docstrings.  Function parameter types also render type links for std library types.

My problem is that my custom types, and those in other dependent libraries, do not correctly render in the function type documentation.

Example:

```py
from typing import Optional
from mylib import MyClass
function my_func(mc: MyClass, should_do_something: Optional[bool]):
   """
   Takes a :class:`mylib.MyClass` and does something if should_do_something is True.

   :param mc: A very important value, regarding 
         :class:`mylib.MyClass` and :class:`mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet`
   :param should_do_something: Whether or not it should.
   """
   pass
```

In the above example, nearly all of the type references render as links, including links to external rtd sites.  The function parameter types render links to the `Optional` and `bool` types on python.org.

**But the parameter types referencing my own types only render in red text with no link.**

Given that manual references work elsewhere in my docs, and even in the :param: docstrings, I feel sure they are wired in correctly.

Is there something I need to know about sphinx extension load ordering?  I don't get any errors from Sphinx, either.

In the image below, you can see most of the parameter types render blue links, but the mongoengine QuerySet parameter, and the ones from my own library, are missing.  Why would this be?

[image]

Comment: I didn't include my `conf.py` in hopes of not providing too much information, and because I think if I had a configuration problem then the other type references wouldn't work.

Comment: In a web browser, Inspect > Source. The HTML markup may provide a clue. Sphinx throws in a *lot* of CSS classes for links.

Comment: @StevePiercy thanks for the tip.  No good info found, though.  The classes are the same.  The only difference I see is that the missing links are literally missing their links, meaning the <code/> tag is not wrapped inside of an <a/> tag.

Comment: @mzjn I mentioned at the top of the original post, that intersphinx is set up and working.  As you can see by the presence of a working link to the QuerySet object next to the bad one, which I added to illustrate the nature of the problem that I am actually having.

Comment: I can almost bet that this will come down to the order that things are rendered in.  If nobody is able to give tips based on what I've given, I'll assemble a complete example.

Comment: That's useful information. A lack of `<a>` tag makes me think that there is no object inventory for the remote library. So I did `python -m sphinx.ext.intersphinx "https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/objects.inv"` and found that the `mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet` class does in fact exist in the `objects.inv`, so that rules out that idea. Let's see if you have configured intersphinx and the entry as `intersphinx_mapping = {"mongoengine": ("https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.io/", None),}` in your `conf.py`.

Comment: On second thought, your `conf.py` probably is correct, as you stated earlier that elsewhere the references generate links as expected. I did see [this comment in the README for `sphinx-autodoc-typehints`](https://github.com/agronholm/sphinx-autodoc-typehints#compatibility-with-sphinxextnapoleon) about putting `sphinx.ext.napoleon` before `sphinx-autodoc-typehints`. Otherwise I am stumped, and would suggest that you file in issue with `sphinx-autodoc-typehints`.

Comment: @TylerGannon adding to the excellent contributions, when you say *"manual references work elsewhere"* do you mean cross-references to your own classes work outside docstrings? Can you elaborate on that? Also, are your classes correctly being inserted in the index and does clicking the index take you to the classes? Did the cross-references work without intershpinx? I haven't had any need to use this combination of extensions from the docs it should be autodoc, napoleon, typehints, in that order where to put intersphinx in that series I don't know.